# Running Flask + Gunicorn + SocketIO

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, gevent-socketio

I am running SocketIOServer for my flask app and I have a run.py script which looks like this:

```
import sys
from idateproto import create_app, run_app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        create_app(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        create_app('dev')
    run_app()
```

and run_app looks like this:

```
def run_app():
    # Run the application
    # See flask/app.py run() for the implementation of run().
    # See http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/serving/ for the parameters of Werkzeug's run_simple()
    # If the debug parameter is not set, Flask does not change app.debug, which is set from
    # the DEBUG app config variable, which we've set in create_app().
    #app.run(**app_run_args)
    global app
    global middleware
    SocketIOServer((app.config['HOST'], app.conf`enter code here`ig['PORT']), middleware,namespace="socket.io", policy_server=False).serve_forever()
```

I run this like: python run.py production/dev/test etc.

Now I want to run it in production using gunicorn and all the tutorials online suggest doing something like:
    gunicorn run:app -c gunicorn-config.py
My problem is I don't want to run just my app any more. I want to tell gunicorn to run the serve_forever method on the SocketIOServer instead, I have done a lot of research online and can not find a way to achieve this. Please help.